# Does single index have benefits when selecting on several columns? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

For example there is a table with columns: ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD

And there are several selects with where clause on:

```
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
ColumnA, ColumnC, ColumnD
ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnD
```

The goal is to speed up these queries. But I don't want to create multi columns indexes for all columns combinations, because it will take a lot of place and may slow down the system.

Is there a sense to create an index just for ColumnA? Will it improve the queries performance?

Thanks

Comment: The question is not if the columns are part of the `select` but if they are part of a condition in the `where` clause.

Comment: The Execution Plan for your queries will show whether, and how, an index is being used. You may be surprised at the choices the query optimizer makes.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are used as a way to reduce "table scanning".  You should index whichever column or combination of columns is used most often.  If that means using 2 columns, that's fine.

Also remember that a CLUSTERED index is a physical page ordering of the data.  NON-CLUSTERED is not.  So, any clustered index is going to be much more efficient.  You could always make the most used field a clustered index, and put a non-clustered index on a field not used as often.

It's all about the data, in the end.  I used to work with healthcare tables that were over 1B records,  Indexing is VERY important in an environment like that.

Comment: The question is the following:
If I have a query like this:
`SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE ColumnA = 'valueA' and ColumnB = 'valueB' and ColumnC = 'valueC'`

Is the index for ColumnA only helpful?

Comment: Is this the ONLY query that will EVER be run on the table?  You have to look at the big picture.  Which field(s) is/are most likely to be used in a WHERE clause in the future?

Comment: `SELECT 1: where ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC  
SELECT 2: where ColumnA, ColumnC, ColumnD  
SELECT 3: where ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnD` for example. 

In each select ColumnA will always come first plus some other columns

Comment: I ask again; is this the ONLY query that will EVER be written against this table?

Comment: No, there are will be 5 or more queries

Comment: OK, so pick the fields that are MOST likely to be queried in the table, and put indexes on them.  If you have one or more fields that will ALWAYS be queried, put clustered indexes on them.  For instance, in my case I had a Customer table.  CustomerID will ALWAYS be used, because that's the field that links to every other table.  That one got a clustered index.  BirthDate was often used in reports, so that one got a non-clustered index.  See?

Comment: Well.... I just wanted to know whether index on one column will improve the query which has the following where clause: first column is the column with index AND some other columns

Comment: There's absolutely NO way to tell that because no one here but you knows what's IN that column.  If it's unrelated to anything else, it's a bad idea.  If it's a key field that is used to join other tables, it's a good idea.  If it's an Integer field, it's a good idea.  If it's a Date field, it's a bad idea.  I don't mean to sound like a jerk, but you really came here with nothing we could use to help you.

Comment: I can see you're new here, so I'm just offering a suggestion that for future questions, either post some actual code or a small 3-or-4 records of your dataset or something like that.  Most of the guys who answer questions here are pretty smart, but they're not mind-readers.  If you include that kind of stuff, you'll get a lot more people to respond and a lot more problem-specific answers.  Cool?